# ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file './scraping/db.opt' (Errcode: 2)

Tags: python, mysql

Working my way through "Web Scraping with Python", and I'm on the part of it where you work with MySQL.  Can't find anything particularly helpful with this error message on Google - can any of you help me decode it? (and hopefully, figure out how to fix it?!)  I'm getting the error after putting in the command:

```
ALTER DATABASE scraping CHARACTER set = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

output:

```
ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file './scraping/db.opt' (Errcode: 2)
mysql>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must ensure your database is named "scraping",
I have ever made this mistake.